# keyboard not operating electronica-bk-0100-01

Tags: keyboards, electronika-bk

I own a Electronica-bk-0100-01.  I have only got around to connecting it up.  Before that I opened up the system, checked for bad tracks, obvious issue etc.  I also checked the end to end of the ribbon type cable connecting the KB to the mother board.

(this is a non membrane keyboard), so it has been switch cleaned etc.

When I power up the system I get 2 beeps and the standard basic prompt/screen but also a "Z" character on screen.  I cant get any keys to go into the basic interpreter - also there is no @beep@ on a key depression.

I dont have an english language manual nor have I yet found a circuit diagram.

Does anybody have experience of this issue - or can you comment.  I though the "Z" key might be stuck down, Mechanically it is not, but I may have to go meter the switch connector?

Any thoughts/experience?

Comment: I have a wee museum in Inverness for DEC Digital PDPs - I have a Saratov(sp) front panel that I am bringing back to life with the help if Jorg kit.  I have been sourcing Russian transistors to fix it.  The Electronika and it are kind of "off the side".  Covid has really screwed up my opening plans!

Comment: When covid blows over I'll be sure to pay you a visit. Seems interesting. My Gaelic by now is so rusty. But in case you need any help with Russian, I'm also active(ish) on Russian.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your Z key is stuck (or perhaps there's a short, or the switch is buggered, or something like that). That would explain the two beeps and the fact a Z appears on the screen when you turn it on.

Better measure the keyboard switch to rule out a problem with it, and also the corresponding trace on the board if you can find it.

Comment: Aidh, switch was eh knackered - shorted.  Cant get inside it (easily) can see the innards after the keycap removed - vanes broken but that would not cause a short.  Hunted for the wee missing bits - no luck.  So I track cut ;-(  I now have a working system - but with no "Z" key.

Comment: @iainmaoileoin You might get some luck asking here: https://zx-pk.ru/forums/59-bk-0010-0011.html. It's a Russian-speaking forum but I think they will be happy to help an English-speaking guy (the forum UI itself could be easily switched to English with a drop-down at the bottom of the page). Or, if you want me to, I could post there and refer to this SO thread asking for further guidance.

Comment: I will give them a try.  Unfortunately I have absolutely no Russian only Gaelic and English.  If I knew a wee bit more about the switch innards I may be able to fix without stripping the whole beast down.